# Get a title from a YouTube video

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

How would I go about getting a title from a YouTube video so I can save my files with that title? I know you can use **gdata-objectivec-client** but I'm a bit confused with it. Because there are just so many files to import and I just do not know what I need to do this. Is **gdata-objectivec-client** all that can be used? Or is there something else I can use to achieve that result?

Answer (score 0):

[YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) will be the best to use. You can get video's details by using [videos->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API call.

You can give it a try in [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list).

Data API has some nice [objective-c examples](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample). We will get more coverage on examples soon.